# Apply a function on columns, without the result replacing the column values based on the outcome of the function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements

(This is basically the dataframe from the picture)

```
structure(list(mz = c(40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90), 
`sample in1` = c(10, 51, 125, 99, 675, 12), 
`sample in2` = c(9, 51, 125, 105, 2424, 5),
`Sample in3` = c(1, 51, 125, 300, 1241, 0.02), 
`blank 1` = c(5, 20, 50, 68, 0, 0),
`blank 2` = c(10, 20, 50, 77, 0, 0),
`blank 3` = c(15, 20, 50, 89, 0, 0.01)), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've got a large dataframe of over 50 columns and 50.000 rows, but this is a simplified version of what I have.

[image]

What I basically need to do, is to summarize the "blank" columns into 1 column. I managed to do this already, using RowMeans on all blank columns.
Next, I want to apply a function to each sample value in my dataframe, the function is: sample value/mean of all blank columns for that specific row = Ratio SB.
The tricky part is: I do not want the result of this function to replace the column values of the sample.
What I want to do, is to either (1) Leave the column value as-is, IF Ratio SB is bigger than a set limit (for example: Ratio SB>2.5, should leave the column value as is). OR (2) return 0 (or NA), in case the result of the SB ratio is smaller than a set limit (for example: if Ratio SB <2.5, return 0 for that specific column value).
Finally (3), the function should NOT be run on samples (or leave sample values as-is) in case the Averaged blank value of that row in the dataframe = 0 (as is the case in the second last row in picture 1)

Those are the 3 essential things for my code.
The output should still be a dataframe and when applying it to the dataframe shown in picture 1, the following changes in the dataframe should occur when running the function I want to make.
[image]

This is what it should look like after applying the code:

```
structure(list(mz = c(40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90), 
`sample in1` = c(NA, 51, NA, NA, 675, 12), 
`sample in2` = c(NA, 51, NA, NA, 2424, 5),
`Sample in3` = c(NA, 51, NA, 300, 1241, NA), 
`Blank Average` = c(10, 20, 50, 78, NA, 0.00333333),
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Up until now I tried the use of case_when, but for this I need to revert to a list structure and can't apply it apparently on a dataframe.
I also tried:  Ratio_X <- sample/averaged blank dataframe[Ratio_x< 2] <- 0 and tried using apply and map_dfc, but none of it worked out. I'm probably doing something terribly wrong and would love it if anyone has any tips or perhaps a solution for me :)

I apologize if anything is unclear, I am a COMPLETE beginner in R and stack overflow. Please let me know if you require additional information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pictures are great for plots, but pretty useless for data. You want help coding, so we need something to test and demonstrate answers on. Please share sample data that we can copy/paste into R - good ways to do this are (a) share code to create/simulate sample data, or (b) use `dput()` to make a copy/pasteable version of data you already have. Something like `dput(your_data[1:5, c("mz", "blank1", "blank2")])` for 5 rows of those three columns. And please show the expected output for your small sample input so your goal is clear. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Akrun and Gregor, thanks for your help! I did not even know about dput(), I've added the code to the original post. Is this enough or do you need more to go by? 
I basically want the "SB ratio" function, to check for all column values whether their SB ratio value is > 2.5 (for example). If that is the case I do not want to change the column value, if that is not the case I want to replace the column value with 0 or NA. Mind that, in case "Background average"= 0, the column values should not change as well (as SB ratio = Sample/Average Blank = sample/0, which is not possible). THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R approach :

```
#Get all the columns which has 'blank' in it
blank_cols <- grep('blank', names(df))
#Get all the columns which has 'sample' in it. 
#Using `ignore.case` because you have "Sample" in 3rd column
sample_cols <- grep('sample', names(df), ignore.case = TRUE)
#Threshold limit to check for
thresh <- 2.5

#Get mean of blank_cols
df$Blank_avg <- rowMeans(df[, blank_cols], na.rm = TRUE)
#Compare sample_cols with the mean, replace them by NA if they are below thresh
df[sample_cols][sweep(df[sample_cols], 1, df1$Blank_avg, `/`) <= thresh] <- NA
#Turn Blank_avg to NA where Blank_avg = 0
df$Blank_avg[df$Blank_avg == 0] <- NA
#Remove blank_cols
result <- df[, -blank_cols]
result
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#     mz `sample in1` `sample in2` `Sample in3` Blank_avg
#  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>
#1    40           NA           NA        NA     10      
#2    50           51           51        51     20      
#3    60           NA           NA        NA     50      
#4    70           NA           NA       300     78      
#5    80          675         2424      1241     NA      
#6    90           12            5       0.02   0.00333
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been a huge help!